# Splitting a complicated string using Regex

Tags: regex, string, split

I'm trying to split strings in a rather specific way. I've been fooling around using the `.split()` and `.replaceall()` methods, but I can't get it right.

Here are a couple of examples of the strings I need to split, followed by how they must be after the splitting. A `,` signifies a new string in the array.

Example 1: `"(and (or (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) )"`

```
"(and", "(or", "(can-hit-robot)", "(wall)", ")", "(can-hit-robot)", "(wall)", ")"
```

Example 2: `"(seq (shoot) (if (can-hit-robot) (shoot) (move) ) )"`

```
"(seq", "(shoot)", "(if", "(can-hit-robot)", "(shoot)", "(move)", ")", ")"
```

Example 3:  `"(while(wall)(if (can-hit-robot)(shoot)(move)))"`

```
"(while", "(wall)", "(if", "(can-hit-robot)", "(shoot)", "(move)", ")", ")"
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I'm *really* struggling to derive your splitting algorithm from your examples, and I've been reverse engineering stuff for nearly 10 years. Admittedly, it's a Saturday morning and my hangover is still raging, but it'd be nice to get a bit of explanation.

Comment: Sorry for that, basically, I'm writing a kind of translator/compiler that converts a string in usable strings that in turn get turned to commands. The parentheses are used to determine a "block", a little bit like { } in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
(?:\s*(?=\())|(?:(?<=\))\s*)
```

It relies on lookbehind though, so engines without lookbehind might not be able to handle this expression. :(

The rule being expressed is, split just before an opening parenthesis and just after a closing parenthesis, also cutting off any spaces on the outside of the parenthesis. The left part of the alternation thus matches spaces leading up to an opening paren; the right part will match spaces continuing after a closing paren.

Comment: Basically the same comment as above.

Thank you. Sorry to bother you further, but how do I enter this? I get errors. (Working in eclipse). My "standard" method to use split goes like this: String pattern = "(?:\s*(?=\())|(?:(?<=\))\s*)" ; return path.split(pattern); But using your pattern like this causes errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What @TimPietzcker said. Also, in the future, any time you have a question on a regexp, be sure to also add a tag for the programming language you're using, since regular expressions are not quite compatible across implementations.

Comment: Will try to remember that. I immediately assumed this was in Java, since I always search this website if I have a java problem. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Without lookbehind assertions: You can split on

```
\s*(?=\(|\B\))
```

This splits before an opening or closing parenthesis (including whitespace), but only if we're not at a word boundary before a closing parenthesis.

Input: `(and (or (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) )`

Output:

```
(and 
(or 
(can-hit-robot) 
(wall) 
) 
(can-hit-robot) 
(wall) 
) 
)
```

Input: `(while(wall)(if (can-hit-robot)(shoot)(move)))`

Output:

```
(while
(wall)
(if 
(can-hit-robot)
(shoot)
(move)
)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to bother you further, but how do I enter this? I get errors. (Working in eclipse).
My "standard" method to use split goes like this:
String pattern = "\s*(?=\(|\B\))" ;
return path.split(pattern);

But using your pattern like this causes errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sven: In a Java string, you need to double the backslashes.

Comment: Thank you, just discovered that too. The String array that results from this does contain between each word an empty string "". Is that due to a faulty implementation on my end or supposed to happen? If it is supposed to happen, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @Sven: I don't see this behaviour in PowerGREP, but it possibly discards empty splits automatically. The behaviour you're seeing actually makes sense because the whitespace token `\s` is optional, therefore the regex matches once with the space and once without. I don't think you can avoid this - another reason why regex is probably not the tool of choice for this.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have a grammar there. Don't go parsing it with regex, use a real parser.

Recommendations:

- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (declarative)
- [JParseC](http://jparsec.codehaus.org/) (programmatic)

Or perhaps you should start by reading something about [Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) in the first place.

Otherwise, [Cthulhu is calling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/342852)

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you're asking for, but I think you'll be better off writing a proper parser. I think you then want to evaluate this expression somehow? You could then parse the input into a tree, which will make your evaluation much easier.

Taking the first example, `(and (or (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) )`, a recursive descent parser would read the `and`, then find a new subexpression (`(or (can-hit-robot) (wall) ) (can-hit-robot) (wall) )`), begin a new child of `and` (`(or (can-hit-robot) (wall) )`), and so on.